# 2d Array as a parameter of a method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, syntax, parameters

[image: Matrix]

I am unfamiliar with how to insert 2d arrays in the parameter of a method. How can I fix this so that it will compile? If you know of any resources that I can read that would be appreciated. I have tried googling "How to use 2d arrays as a parameter", but I came up short, thank you.

Comment: What languages is this? Java?

Comment: Add the tag of the language you are using

Comment: Yes Java. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is java. If so you should do

```
public static void mult(int[][] A, int[][] B, int[][] C)
```

You can't get the length as a parameter. You would have to do `A.length` for one dimension and `A[i].length` for second dimension.